# Why does Firefox not honor CSS font-size for code tags wrapped in pre?

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

I've found an inconsistency among browsers in handling font-size (on Mac OS X 10.11.4). I'd like to know if this is a bug in Firefox, or a bug in CSS, or am I not understanding something about CSS?

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neumini/5p5n9ysm/) shows the details.  In a section like this:

```
<pre>Start of pre section
  <code>**problem here!**</code>
End of pre section
</pre>
```

the style `code { font-family: Courier; }` changes the font-size shown by Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox. Yet in other sections, the `code` element size increases from 13px to 16px in all the browsers.

Why does the font-size increase from 13px to 16px after setting the `font-family` in all browsers?

Perhaps Firefox *is* changing the `font-family` but not the `font-size`.  Yet it *does* change the font-size in other places, like in `code` inside a `p` element or inside a list.

I'm guessing the solution is to just aggressively set explicit font size with pixel units wherever I care about it (ignoring accessibility).

---

Quote from possibly related Firefox bug from 2006: [Bug 328621 - strange default `monospace` font size -- differs from the proportional fonts](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=328621)

> Though the inter-browser portability problem this imposes doesn't seem that trivial to me. The last time I wanted to markup HTML so that the monospaced parts showed the same in both Mozilla and M$IE I had to resort to absolute font sizes, which should be certainly avoided due to the accessibility problems they impose.
>
> And yes, there's a simple workaround -- changing the settings. But most of the users will use defaults. :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue is not new; it has been known for many years that [browser handling of monospace fonts is incredibly screwy](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2010/02/12/fixed-monospace-sizing) and inconsistent across browsers. A number of workarounds are available that don't require you to override the monospace font preference set by the user, the most perplexing of which is to specify

```
font-family: monospace, monospace;
```

That's right: *two* `monospace` keywords at the end of the font stack. Nobody knows why this works; it just does.

For what it is worth, Firefox's UA stylesheet contains references to a `-moz-fixed` keyword which refers to the preference that is set by the user, which includes both the family *and* the size despite it being a value for the `font-family` property. Firefox ships with the preference set to 13px in whichever the system's default monospace font is. It would seem that `monospace, monospace` forces the browser to compute the element's font-size according to the spec while still preserving the preferred monospace family, at least. But this is just a guess.

Is this a bug? It depends on whom you ask. If you ask browser vendors, they'll probably say this is intentional. If you ask other authors, they'll probably also call it a bug. Is this a spec violation? No, because the spec allows browsers to implement defaults however they like.

Answer (score 3):

Since I asked the question and got a couple of good faith answers that are however not really answering my question: I'm going to try to prove that this really is a problem with current browsers.  See my comment at the end about why this might or might not matter.

Here then are

## 3 problems with font-size in CSS/HTML in FireFox, Chrome and Safari on Mac OS X 10.11.4:

### Problem 1.  Changing font-family should not change font-size, but it sometimes does.

I don't know what the "user agent stylesheet" is.  There can be all kinds of settings on it.  But regardless of those settings, changing `font-family` should not change computed `font-size`.  (Some fonts might appear larger at the same font size compared to other fonts at same font size, so visually they can look bigger or smaller, but the computed font size number should not change).

notation:  in the following

```
pre(code) means roughly <pre><code>text here</code></pre>
p(code) means roughly <p><code>text here</code></p>
```

In the default situation, a page with no styles, I see this in all 3 browsers:

```
pre=13px
pre(code)=13px
p=16px
p(code)=13px
```

```html
<pre>pre <code>pre(code)</code></pre>
<p>paragraph <code>p(code)</code></p>
```

Perhaps the user agent stylesheet is something like this:

```
pre { font-size: 13px }
code { font-size: 13px }
p { font-size: 16px }
```

The user agent can't be using relative sizes for `code`, because it appears as 13px inside of both `pre` and `p` elements.  So it could be this:

```
pre { font-size: 81.25% }
code { font-size: 13px }
p { font-size: 100% }
```

or the equivalent using `em` instead of percentage.  Or perhaps a descendent rule with percentages or `em`:

```
pre { font-size: 81.25% }
pre code { font-size: 100% }
p { font-size: 100% }
p code { font-size: 81.25% }
```

But then how do we explain this:

After setting `code { font-family: Courier }`  (or any font family other than `monospace`) we get:

```
pre=13px
pre(code)=16px for Chrome & Safari    pre(code)=13px for FireFox
p=16px
p(code)=16px
```

```css
code { font-family: "Courier"; }
```

```html
<pre>pre <code>pre(code)</code></pre>
<p>paragraph <code>p(code)</code></p>
```

No matter what the stylesheet is, the `font-size` should not change after only changing the `font-family`.

### Problem 2. Relative `font-size` should be based on parent element's computed `font-size`.  But it sometimes is not.

With no styles we have:

```
p=16px
p(code)=13px
```

After setting `code { font-size: 100%; }` we should have

```
p=16px
p(code)=16px
```

Instead we still have:

```
p=16px
p(code)=13px
```

This is wrong because author style should override default user-agent (browser) style.  And relative (percentage) font-size is based on the parent element's computed font-size.

```css
code { font-size: 100%; }
```

```html
<p>paragraph <code>p(code)</code></p>
```

Similarly, after setting `code { font-size: 120%; }` we should have

```
p=16px
p(code)=19.2px = 16px * 1.2
```

Instead we have:

```
p=16px
p(code)=15.6px = 13px * 1.2
```

```css
code { font-size: 120%; }
```

```html
<p>paragraph <code>p(code)</code></p>
```

This shows that parent element is being ignored, and that some phantom value of 13px is being used to calculate the relative `font-size`.

### Problem 3. The standard advice to use `html { font-size: 62.5% }` and then use `em` or `rem` for font-sizing does not work correctly

(Note: FireFox with `rem` does seem to be correct)

(Note: using the also recommended `body { font-size: 62.5% }` seemed to produce some crazy results, like doubling of font sizes, so I'm not considering that here.)

With `html { font-size: 62.5%; }` and `code { font-size: 1.6em; }` we have:

```
p=10px
FireFox: p(code)=13.0167px
Chrome: p(code)=13px
Safari: p(code)=13px
```

These should all be 16px = 1.6 * 10px

```css
body { font-size: 62.5%; } 
code { font-size: 1.6em; }
```

```html
<p>paragraph <code>p(code)</code></p>
```

With `html { font-size: 62.5%; }` and `code { font-size: 1.6rem; }` we have:

```
p=10px
FireFox: p(code)=16px
Chrome: p(code)=13px
Safari: p(code)=13px
```

FireFox is the only browser to get it right here.

```css
html { font-size: 62.5%; } 
code { font-size: 1.6rem; }
```

```html
<p>paragraph <code>p(code)</code></p>
```

I suspect this all doesn't matter much because people are used to slapping font-size styles all over the place in their CSS.

From my reading, there has been an attempt to make web pages more responsive to the native settings on each device: to adapt to varying hardware with more or fewer pixels per inch (PPI); to allow users with reduced vision to request larger text so they can read more easily; etc.

There are various recommendations and a bit of controversy about how to best do this: [specify font-size with `html { font-size: 62.5% }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) and [use `em` or `rem` everywhere](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/comprehensive-guide-when-to-use-em-vs-rem--cms-23984) seems to be a popular opinion. Lately [just using good old `px` to specify font-size is coming back in style](https://mindtheshift.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/r-i-p-rem-viva-css-reference-pixel/), with the idea that `px` does not specify actual screen pixels but rather an idealized 96 dpi for the viewer (which may translate to a different number of pixels) and letting the browser's zoom controls handle user desired changes in font-size.

In summary, I think these problems with font size **argue against the logic behind most of the advice about "responsive design" for font size**.  My guess is that this is an area where there is a lot of history factored into how browsers work, and it's near impossible to change now.  And of course there are millions of websites with existing code that are all presumably happy with how font sizing is working now.

It seems to me that the only way to get consistent font sizing is to use pixels: `px`. For example, [px at the Root, rem for Components, em for Text Elements](https://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/).  Or just [just use pixels](https://benfrain.com/just-use-pixels/) everywhere.

Mozilla writes the following about [accessibility and font-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)

> Defining font sizes in pixel is not accessible, because the user cannot change the font size from the browser. (For example, users with limited vision may wish to set the font size much larger than the size chosen by a web designer.) Therefore, avoid using pixels for font sizes if you wish to create an inclusive design.

But with all these bugs with inherited and relative font size it doesn't seem like an option to avoid using pixels.  Plus the argument about a [reference pixel](https://mindtheshift.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/r-i-p-rem-viva-css-reference-pixel/) and using the browser's zoom control seems to solve the accessibility issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the font-size increase from 13px to 16px after setting the
>   font-family in all browsers?

probably because the browser's default stylesheet has these settings.

> I'm guessing the solution is to not try to understand all this but
>   just aggressively set font and font-size wherever I care about it.

Not sure what you mean by "agressivly" but yes: If you have particular demand for that style, set it as precisely as possible in your own stylesheet, including font familiy, weight, size etc.

Answer (score 1):

That's because back in the dark ages one Netscape dev decided to force his personal preferences on everyone else in the browser settings (most coders are young people who think it is smart to destroy their eyes by setting text size one or two sizes smaller than everyone else, they think "monospace" belong to them and "sans serif" to normal human beings).

Thus, Firefox ships with defaults that alias "monospace" to a smaller font size than "sans serif". Pretty much destroys coordinated font sets (where the monospace font is designed to look the same as the serif or sans serif one).

You can "fix" it locally by launching about:config and changing all font.size.fixed.* properties to the same value as font.size.variable.* ones. But since you can't fix all Firefoxes in the wild, that makes the monospace css alias useless for this browser.

Comment: This sounds like a plausible explanation for why things are messed up now with monospace fonts.  However I'm finding that the `font-family: monospace, monospace;` fix is working. I guess the main problem is it's a hack and could stop working at any time. Have you tried the `monospace, monospace` fix?

Comment: Yes the main problem is that's a hack, so who can tell if browser devs check this case when they release new versions? I suppose it works because when you use a single "monospace", the browser code detects it matches the "monospace" property and clamps the size to the 13px default. When you use two "monospaces", the browser uses normal css stack sizing rules, because the browser dev forgot to special-case "monospace" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Response from [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1524623/) moved from question to answer:</sub>

---

The answer from BoltClock was super helpful. The page he/she referenced about [Fixed Monospace Sizing by Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2010/02/12/fixed-monospace-sizing/) has a thorough analysis and some solutions. It explains some of the browser mechanics related to when the user's font preferences are used, which explains some of the mysterious behavior I was seeing (e.g. why was the `code` element seeming to inherit a size of 13px when it was the child of a `p` element with size of 16px: the reason is it actually inherits size `medium` which causes the browser to use the default browser/user preferences).

For my situation I'm finding I can remove the `html { font-size: 16px; }` style and instead add the following:

```
pre { font-family: monospace, monospace; }
code { font-family: monospace, monospace; font-size: 100%; }
```

This gives me consistent relative font-sizing but still allows the user to set the default font-size. Eric Meyer recommends using `monospace, serif` but I'm finding that `monospace, monospace` works, and I think it makes a little more sense when you see it in a style-sheet (it's odd, but looks probably intentional, and it means you really, really want monospace).

I think that the ultimate problem is that the browsers have different font-size defaults/preferences for monospace font, than for other fonts. The main idea of "accessible responsive design" in regards to font-size is to let the user have control over font-size. But when we have several settings for font size (serif, sans-serif, monospace) then that's too many options for the user to set. The user just wants bigger text that they can read.  But for the author: they just want the relative sizes of the fonts to be correct at whatever given size.

In case it's helpful to someone else, here are some examples (in the [slick Eric Meyer style](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/monospaced3.html)) showing that `monospace, monospace` fixes some of the problems I wrote about in my own answer below.

```css
code:before {
    content: attr(style); 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA; 
    color: #575; margin-right: 0.5em;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a 'p' element with a <code>'code' element</code> contained within.</p>
<p>This is a 'p' element with a <code style="font-family: monospace">'code' element</code> contained within.</p>
<p>This is a 'p' element with a <code style="font-family: monospace, monospace">'code' element</code> contained within.</p>
<p>This is a 'p' element with a <code style="font-size: 100%">'code' element</code> contained within.</p>

<p>This is a 'p' element with a <code style="font-family: monospace; font-size: 100%">'code' element</code> contained within.</p>

<p>This is a 'p' element with a <code style="font-family: monospace, monospace; font-size: 100%">'code' element</code> contained within.</p>
<p>This is a 'p' element with a <code style="font-family: monospace; font-size: 120%">'code' element</code> contained within.</p>

<p>This is a 'p' element with a <code style="font-family: monospace, monospace; font-size: 120%">'code' element</code> contained within.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue where I used monospace and the sizes were different in Google Chrome and Edge & Mozilla Firefox. This is because different browsers have different font weights and sizes for *standard* fonts.
To resolve this issue I used Google fonts and then the fonts sizes were the same in all browsers.