# "font-family: monospace, monospace"

Tags: css, monospace, normalize-css

In `normalize.css`, the monospace font rules contain

```
font-family: monospace, monospace;
```

Is this different to

```
font-family: monospace;
```

?

There must be a reason for using that. Maybe it's a workaround for the behaviour of some browsers?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You are right. The `font-family: monospace, monospace;` declaration is a simple hack/workaround for some browsers which tend to reduce the font size of monospace fonts.

**More info on this Github issue:** https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/519#issuecomment-197131966

Answer (score 39):

Yes, this is a workaround for a *long-standing* (I'm talking over a decade) issue with browsers' handling of the `monospace` generic family. [Eric Meyer has a detailed write-up on this](https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2010/02/12/fixed-monospace-sizing), and I explored this recently while [answering this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524272/possible-firefox-font-size-bug-does-not-honor-css-font-size-for-code-tag-wrappe/36540436#36540436) that's specifically about Firefox's handling of monospace fonts.

*Why* does it work? *How* is `monospace, monospace` different to just `monospace`? Nobody knows. I made a guess based on Firefox's behavior, but it's just that: a guess. But one thing is clear: `monospace, monospace` is *recommended* over just `monospace` if you don't want to deal with this behavior.