# Font size issue with firefox and <code> tags

Tags: html, css, firefox, font-size

I am generating a html documentation with sphinx-docs.

The links to functions are generated as  tags inside  blocks. The css font-size properties are 0.9em for both regular text and for the links. I have cleaned all other font-size properties in order to be sure of where the issue comes from.

In Firefox, the computed size for regular text is 14.4px while the  blocks are 11.7px

In Internet Explorer and Chrome, everything is 14.4px

So it seems that firefox defines a different em base value for regular text and . And in order to have the same display in all browser, I have to fix  font-size to pixel values, which is quite ugly.

Is this a known issue and is there a workaround other than not using  at all?

Comment: 0.9em ... edited

Comment: According to the answer I have linked to, `rem` does work in firefox but screws things in other browsers...

Comment: @Martin: That doesn't mean anything. A browser can claim support for a feature but actually have bugs. And an unofficial resource like caniuse.com can claim that a browser supports a feature but either mention only the most notable, or not mention any, of a plethora of quirks and bugs specific to that browser. The author of the linked question has provided test cases that demonstrate `rem` not working correctly in some browsers, thereby either refuting that claim, or pointing to some other mysterious behavior that is not covered by a simple "I support `rem` or not" statement.

Comment: The only glitch with `rem` is when you are dumb enough to give `html` a font size in rems. E.g. `html {font-size: 0.625rem;}` resulting in 1rem being equal to 0.625rem. Not all browsers handle this paradox in the same way. Otherwise, it just works everywhere. @BoltClock The linked question is about monospace, not rems.

Comment: @Mr Lister: And the self-answer therein demonstrates how using rems is not an acceptable workaround for the monospace problem.

Comment: @Mr Lister: You've got me curious about that root-font-size-in-rems issue though. That example should result in the root element having a font-size of 0.625 * the user- or browser-defined medium font-size preference, and rems on descendant elements being calculated off of this size. Which browsers behave differently?

Comment: @BoltClock Can't reproduce it now, but a few years back Chrome did not always handle `html {font-size: 2rem} body {font-size: .5rem}` correctly; this would sometimes show in the default size, sometimes at half the size. Sometimes, a refresh or a "Inspect element" would switch between the two, or it would briefly flash the text at half size before returning to normal. But apparently, they fixed things.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Ah, ***C h r o m e***

Answer (score 0):

The problem is discussed and precisely answered here:

[Why does Firefox not honor CSS font-size for code tags wrapped in pre?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524272/why-does-firefox-not-honor-css-font-size-for-code-tags-wrapped-in-pre)

The main solution being to use a strange CSS hack:

```
font-family: monospace, monospace;
```